# Problems simplifying expression including imaginary part

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to simplify this expression

```
expr = -2 π Im[(a b (b - l) o)/(k l (b^2 + 4 o^2 π^2))] + 
   a b (b l + 4 o^2 π^2) Re[1/(b^2 k l + 4 k l o^2 π^2)]

Simplify[Re[expr],  Assumptions -> {Element[{o, a, b, k, l}, Reals]}]
```

which returns

$$a b \left(b l+4 \pi ^2 o^2\right) \Re\left(\frac{1}{b^2 k l+4 \pi ^2 k l o^2}\right)-2 \pi  \Im\left(\frac{a b o (b-l)}{k l \left(b^2+4 \pi ^2 o^2\right)}\right).$$

Why is the imaginary part not set to zero, although I have stated that all parameter are real? What am I missing?

Comment: try `ComplexExpand`?

Comment: Is it easy to understand, why that is necessary?

Comment: [Re >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Re.html) says: "_Re[expr] is left unevaluated if expr is not a numeric quantity._" (same for  `Im`). Since the arguments of `Im` and `Re` in your expression are not numeric quantities, `Im[a1]` and `Re[a2]` do not evaluate to `0` and `a2`. `ComplexExpand`  _expands expr assuming that all variables are real._ (and, it seems, it forces evaluation of `Im[...]` and `Re[...]`)

Comment: Thank you, that helps.

Comment: AskingQuestions, my pleasure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ComplexExpand @ Re[expr]
```

> (a b^2 l)/(b^2 k l + 4 k l o^2 π^2) + (4 a b o^2 π^2)/(
>       b^2 k l + 4 k l o^2 π^2)

```
Simplify[%]
```

> (a b^2 l + 4 a b o^2 π^2)/(b^2 k l + 4 k l o^2 π^2)

```
% // TeXForm
```

> $\frac{a b^2 l+4 \pi ^2 a b o^2}{b^2 k l+4 \pi ^2 k l o^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Just one remark:

The Simplification you asked for also works without ComplexExpand.
Therefor you have to give assumptions, which make Re[] evaluable.

In your case

```
Simplify[Re[expr],Assumptions -> {Element[{o, a, b, k, l}, Reals], b^2 k l + 4 k l o^2 \[Pi]^2 != 0}]
(*(a b (b l + 4 o^2 \[Pi]^2))/(b^2 k l + 4 k l o^2 \[Pi]^2)*)
```

you must avoid vanishing Denominator in `expr`.

Comment: Good point.....